# GetRequiredService<DbContextOptions<MovieContext>> v.s. GetRequiredService<MovieContext>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am reading [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/sql) and found two approaches used by the author to obtain `MovieContext`.

In `SeedData.Initialize`, `MovieContext` is obtained as follows.

```
public static class SeedData
{
    public static void Initialize(IServiceProvider isp)
    {
        DbContextOptions<MovieContext> options = 
        isp.GetRequiredService<DbContextOptions<MovieContext>>();

        using (var context = new MovieContext(options))
        {  
            // trimmed for simplicity 
        }
    }
}
```

But in `Program.Main`, the context is obtain as follows.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IWebHost iwh = BuildWebHost(args);

        using (IServiceScope iss = iwh.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            IServiceProvider isp =  iss.ServiceProvider;

            try
            {
                MovieContext context = isp.GetRequiredService<MovieContext>();
                // trimmed for simplicity
            }

        }
    }

}
```

## Question

Is there any difference between

```
new MovieContext(isp.GetRequiredService<DbContextOptions<MovieContext>>());
```

and

```
isp.GetRequiredService<MovieContext>();
```

where `isp` is of type `IServiceProvider` ?

Comment: In the first example you manually instantiate the context and the container resolves and instantiates the options. in the second the container handles everything. It will resolve the option and inject it into the context when it is being resolved. the first is commonly known as Pure DI.

Comment: Totally a matter of preference. Both can be done as the end result is the same depending on how the context was registered with the IoC container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any difference between the two approaches.

In the first example you manually instantiate the context and inject its [explicit dependency](http://deviq.com/explicit-dependencies-principle/) by using the container to resolve and instantiate the options (Service Locator).

In the second example the container handles everything. It will resolve the option and inject it into the context when it is being resolved.

> When do we need to do the former and the latter approach?

Totally a matter of preference. Both can be done as the end result is the same depending on how the context was registered with the IoC container.

Comment: No. it is not. I can only assume what their intentions were. Your suggestion to use the single instance is a good approach. The context will be disposed when it goes out of scope just before the host is started.